# How to convert dds to DGEList for kegga() analysis in R?

Tags: r, matrix, rna-seq

Disclaimer: I'm very new to R!

I have some differential expression data from an `RNAseq` experiment, and I'm trying to use `kegga()` to look at up and down regulation in different pathways.

I've used `DESeq2` for my differential expression, and I need to convert my `dds` object to a `DGEList` to use as an argument for `kegga()` but it isn't working.

```
dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = data, colData = sampleInfo, design = ~ groups)
dge <- as.DGEList(dds)
```

It just returns:

> Error in as.DGEList(dds) : could not find function "as.DGEList"

Anyone know what to do? I've definitely installed & loaded `DESeq2` and `edgeR` etc.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for your first error is that the package is not loaded. If you've installed DEFormats then load it with library(), otherwise install it from Bioconductor then load it.

https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/DEFormats.html

To continue with the analysis you'll need to perform some pre-processing steps then compute the DE genes.

```
design <- model.matrix(~ groups)

dge <- as.DGEList(dds)
dge <- calcNormFactors(dge)
dge <- estimateDisp(dge, design, robust=TRUE)
fit_dge <- glmQLFit(dge, design, robust=TRUE)

# change names below to specify the groups you want to compare 
my_contrast <- makeContrasts(genotypeN2-genotypeVC222, levels=design)
de_result <- glmQLFTest(fit_dge, contrast=my_contrast)
topTags(de_result)
keg <- kegga(de_result, species="Mm")
```

You can also look at the package ClusterProfiler, it is a really good interface for doing pathway annotation using multiple ontologies and it has pretty straightforward implementation whether you're using DEseq, edgeR, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about DEFormats. I've now converted `dds` to a `DGEList`, but I'm having trouble getting it to work as an argument for `kegga()`. Do you know what I need to change it to to get it to work? Thanks so much!

`data_kegg <- kegga(dge, species="Mm")
Error in kegga.default(dge, species = "Mm") : 
  components of de should be vectors`

Comment: You can't directly put the DGE object into the pathway analysis, you need to fit your data with normalization factors and dispersion estimates, then compute the DE genes first.

Comment: Check out the edits to the answer above. You should take a look at a walk-through like the one linked below to better understand what the steps are doing. They also include visualizations to help QC your data which is very important!

https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/workflows/vignettes/RnaSeqGeneEdgeRQL/inst/doc/edgeRQL.html